# how to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'daphne' in django WebSocket

Tags: django, websocket, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to get a WebSocket running for a Django project I'm working on, but I can't get the WebSocket to connect, which is strange since I copied the example chat application.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'core',
    'room',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'WeChat.asgi.application'
```

HTML part

```
{% block scripts %}

{{ room.slug|json_script:"json-roomname" }}

<script>
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-roomname').textContent);
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
        + roomName
        + '/'
    );

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log('onmessage')
    }

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e){
        console.log('onclose')
    }
</script>
    
{% endblock %}
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .import consumers

websoscket_urlpatterns =[
    path('ws/<str:room_name>/',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
    
]
```

asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter

import room.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'WeChat.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http" : get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket" : AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            room.routing.websoscket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

consumers.py

```
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

First time I'm using the WebSocket. I run the Python file and inspect the browser but I got an unexpected error like

**Python:64 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/Python/' failed:
(anonymous) @ Python:64**

it shows the redline under the ( new WebSocket)

```
const chatSocket = new WebSocket('ws://'
       + window.location.host
       + '/ws/'
       + roomName
       + '/'
   );
```

First, I got an error like this then I run the command **python -m pip install -U channels["daphne"]** then I add **daphne** to the installed app. But after that, I got an unexpected error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'daphne'** Anyone, please help me to fix this error?

Comment: @mpliax bro can u please help me

Answer (score 1):

Run Commands

```
- pip uninstall channels
- python -m pip install -U channels["daphne"]
```

Remove `'channels'` from **`INSTALLED_APPS`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "daphne",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
)
```